# PowerShell - Empty Junk Email

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

I tried to empty the Junk email in this way. It only marks the emails read but does not empty the folder.

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$junk = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(23)
$junk.Items | %{$_.Unread = $false} | %{$_.Delete()} 
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook)
Remove-Variable Outlook
```

I used Exchange Web Services earlier and I could but the code isn't elegant:

```
$junk.Empty([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DeleteMode]::HardDelete, $true)
```

EDIT:

I can partially delete with this

```
$junk | ForEach-Object {$_.Delete()}
```

By which I mean it only deletes the emails few at a time and then moves them to the Deleted Items. I wish they were just emptied.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "for each" loop when you are changing the collection - loop from Items.Count down to 1.

Comment: I don't prefer to use the foreach.

Comment: Is it not what you are using above?

Comment: I'm sorry if I confused. I want the first part of my question to work:                          `Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$junk = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(23)
$junk.Items | %{$_.Unread = $false} | %{$_.Delete()} 
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook)
Remove-Variable Outlook`